# What is XDQP in MarkLogic Replication

Tags: database-replication, marklogic

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/configuring

I was reading the documentation on Data Replication, the section on security, and it references XDQP, but searching the documents and developer.marklogic.com, I was not able to find anything that describes what XDQP means.  Can someone please clarify and point me to documentation with more information?

Answer (score 3):

XDQP is the protocol MarkLogic nodes use to talk to each other.

The name is an acronym for XML Data Query Protocol, if I remember right, but it's evolved to be more than that.

It's an undocumented internal-only protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The most relevant points needed to be considered

- Its a TCP/IP based (but not HTTP) protocol and runs on port 7999 by default (changeable)
- Multiple sockets are opened to each host for redundancy
- All hosts in a cluster need to be able to communicate on that port at all times to all other hosts.  The 'hostnames' of each host must resolve independently to an IP address it can be reached by all other hosts in the cluster. (not necessarily the same IP as a client connection)
- Therefore any firewall, iptables, routers, network security etc needs to be configured to allow bi directional TCP/IP initiated and received by all hosts in a cluster to all other hosts at a TCP/IP level (not HTTP) without port rewriting or content based filtering/routing.
- There is a continual 'heartbeat' synchronizing all servers to the same clock (transaction timestamp) and keeping a consistent state of the 'quorum' and propagating configuration change.  If this is interrupted a host will become disconnected from the cluster.  If that host has critical data the cluster may stop being fully functional.
- Monitoring the traffic patterns (not content) can sometimes be useful in debugging or predicting performance issues or unusual behaviour
- Any 'dead periods' between any 2 hosts on this port is an indication of some kind problem, conversely any interruption of networking availability on this port will cause the cluster to rejoin and determine if the subset of hosts accessible by any one host is sufficient to be a 'quorum' (the 'live' part of the cluster) or if the host(s) are the non-active part of a disjoint cluster.